# Window reference got from window.open() gets closed automatically in Browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, window.open, window-object

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open wikipidia.org in a chrome tab and open the devtools.
2. Enter the following command

`p = window.open('https://www.google.com')`

Once the window opens, entering `p.closed` returns true.

But, If we replace the url of target window from https://www.google.com to https://www.yahoo.com, `p.closed` returns false

Am I missing something?

Comment: `window.closed` always returns `true` if the opener is not on the same domain as the opener, and if certain headers have not been set in the response. yahoo.com has set those headers. I can't remember exactly what headers/CORS is required, but you should be able to research those if necessary. The main point is that you (as the client opening third party sites) cannot rely on `window.closed` being accurate when working with third-party/cross-domain sites.

Comment: Thank you. Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response works. Would you allow me to post your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I closed it as a duplicate.